# A more inclusive Salesforce SE

Tags: discussion

What can we be doing to bring more admin types into this Stackexchange? This has become a help site dominated by developer questions. Is it unreasonable to hope that we could eventually have a site where people actually do come here to ask questions about formulas, complex administration tasks, and problem solving outside of the world of the developer?

Comment: I realize there was a question already about "can I ask administrative questions". I think that has been established. What I'm asking is how do we get more of them?

Answer (score 11):

Great question — from the start my intention was to have admins and developers using this as solutions to problems can cover aspects of the system across the board. Most of the time when I've tried to hint to admins though they tend to already be users of Salesforce Answers so are less inclined to try this, and now the developer ratio is putting people off I think.

What we really need is some people who write admin related blogs to start using it and promoting it, and also for developers working with admins to encourage the administrators to take part.

We could also populate the site a few admin type questions ourselves to help encourage growth in that area.

Comment: Great ideas! [It's OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).  If someone solves an interesting admin problem during the course of their normal work they can feel free to post the question and answer at the same time, even though they already have a solution.  Maybe they'll end up getting an interesting answer or different way of doing it from someone else and learn something. I'd appreciate learning about the interesting admin problems people run into and solve.

Answer (score 5):

At the moment the Salesforce Answers site provides an excellent experience for Salesforce admins - so why would they come to Stack Exchange?  It would offer a similar Q&A style format, but with none of the recognised experts to provide answers or the breadth and depth of community.

There needs to be a key differentiator - something that elevates SE over the Answers site.  If what's on offer is less of the same, its hardly a compelling reason to switch.